# WPF image inside Image not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, image, grid

I'm trying to include a picture inside another picture in WPF. I need to do this in order to "fill" a certain part of the root image if a certain event occurs. In order to acomplish this, I used a Grid, added the initial image into it and added a second grid containing the image in the grid. 
In the designer everything looks fine: 
[image]

But when i start the application the image to fill the part of the root image doesn't show up:
[image]

Here is my XAML code:

```
 <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">

                <Image 
                        Source="Sourceimage.png"
                        Name="SourceImage">

                </Image>
                <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.272,0.664" Margin="47,387,1019.4,103"
                      >

                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="-47.522"/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>

                    <Image
                        Source="fillimage.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="-2,-7,2,-1">
                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="47.954"/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Image.RenderTransform>

                    </Image>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
```

I don't know how to implement that better. If you have a solution, please let me know...

Comment: The purpose of the inner Grid is unclear. Why don't you simply put the two Images on top of each other in a single Grid (cell), and set the second Image's RenderTransform appropriately?

Comment: Did that, didn't work out